# Variable DIV height

Tags: javascript, html, css

I got this div structure:
[image: Structure]

DIV3 has a fixed height.

The nested DIV5 gonna get the content from Ajax, so the height will change. Plus, there are some DHTML inside it that changes the height too. DIV5 has a min-height fixed.

DIV6 has fixed content, but height must change according DIV5 height.

The problem: If I set DIV6 height as 'auto', size is ok, but scrollbar is not functional. If I set as '100%' scrollbar works, but end of the DIV6 is cut, according DIV5 increases its height.

Don't sure it's clear enough...

The code:

```
    <div style="height: 850px; width: 1000px; display: table;">
    <div style="height: 850px; float: left;"></div>
    <div style="height: 850px; width: 598px; float: left;">
        <div id="DIV5" style="max-height: 200px; width: 598px; overflow-x: hidden; overflow-y: scroll;"></div>
        <div id="DIV6" style="height: 200px; width: 598px; overflow-x: hidden; overflow-y: scroll;"></div>
    </div>
<div id="definicoes" style="height: 850px; width: 200px; float: left;"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: to work scroll bar you have to give height for DIV6, height auto won't work

Comment: Its always better to share a jsfiddle link in cases like this. Easier to explain the problem as well as to answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting Div 6 bottom: 0px; However I'd calculate heights with js using jquery.

Comment: This should be a comment.

Comment: why? it's an answer not a question to the question nor comment.

Comment: Welcome back mate @davefrassoni , Happy to see your comment after long 5 years.  Let me up vote your comment :)